# Change macro for the route you take, be the one that indicates a cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro that lists the files in a certain folder and places them in a listbox. The address where it takes the address is in static form. I would like you to indicate to me that this address depends on the route that is in cell J1. The macro is as follows

```
Private Sub Userform_initialize()
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    c00 = "C:\Users\Downloads" 'change path to suit
    c01 = Dir(c00 & "*.pdf")
    With CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
        Do While c01 <> "" c02 = c02 & "|" & .GetBaseName(c00 & c01)
            c01 = Dir
        Loop
    End With
    With ListBox1
        .ListIndex = -1
        .List = Split(Mid(c02, 2), "|")
    End With
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub

Private Sub ListBox1_Click() 'change path to suit 
    Filename = "C:\User\Downloads\" & ListBox1.Value & ".pdf"
    ShellExecute 0, "Open", Filename, "", "", vbMaximizedFocus
    ListBox1.ListIndex = -1 
End Sub
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code there.  Use the `{}` button to format it.

Comment: I hope I formated your post right. Do you need any further information? May you mark an answer?

Comment: @Nirostar Thank you very much for your response, I appreciate your cooperation. see you soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace the static string with the the value of Range("J1")

```
Private Sub Userform_initialize()
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    c00 = Range("J1").Value 'change path to suit
    c01 = Dir(c00 & "*.pdf")
    With CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
        Do While c01 <> "" c02 = c02 & "|" & .GetBaseName(c00 & c01)
            c01 = Dir
        Loop
    End With
    With ListBox1
        .ListIndex = -1
        .List = Split(Mid(c02, 2), "|")
    End With
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub

Private Sub ListBox1_Click() 'change path to suit 
    Filename = Range("J1").Value & ListBox1.Value & ".pdf"
    ShellExecute 0, "Open", Filename, "", "", vbMaximizedFocus
    ListBox1.ListIndex = -1 
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response, I appreciate your cooperation. see you soon.

Comment: @Bastionfutbolclub May you mark it as an answer then?